# Java, Spring setting up themes confusing and not working

Tags: java, css, spring, themes

spring-servlet.xml setting up theme beans:

```
<bean id="themeSource"
class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />  // also tried WEB-INF.resources.theme- and WEB-INF/resources/theme- here, same problem
</bean>

<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</bean>

<bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

under WEB-INF/resources, where are 3 theme files:

1. theme-black.properties
2. theme-blue.properties
3. theme-default.properties

each file contain this accordingly:

```
css=themes/black.css
css=themes/blue.css
css=themes/default.css
```

i have folder WEB-INF/themes , which contains 3 of these css files, i think the content of css isn't important here.

now error i run into is :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Theme 'default': No message found under code 'css' for locale 'en'.
```

so basically it just can't find the css value for themes, which means it can't find the properties file...

what I am doing wrong? feel free to ask questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to put theme properties into classpath (as is written in [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s07.html)). Classpath is not /WEB-INF folder. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305285/servlet-containers-and-class-path) for clarity.

> By default the delegate will be a
>   org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource that
>   loads properties files from the root of the classpath.

Comment: Isn't the classes folder and the files in there generated by itself? Shouldn't there be a way, that it would work without manually putting the files in there...?

Comment: I don't get the "manually putting files" into folder. How else do you want to put files in folder? I bet you also put property files into /WEB-INF folder manually.

Comment: classes folder and class files in it are generated automatically, I do not make that folder myself nor class files.

Comment: Are you using IDE? If you're using any IDE then it should support "classpath" folder. Just put property files in there and they will be "generated" automatically? If you aren't using IDE specify the classpath like this `java -classpath /path`.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, but I deploy with ant.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipse but try create `/WEB-INF/classes` folder and add property files into it. They should be pre-built at runtime. Or try to put your files in directory according [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000546/a-question-about-eclipse-and-classpath-in-a-run-configuration/1000581#1000581).

Answer (score 0):

If you do don't want to put the theme.properties file under "classes" folder, you can put it under "META-INF" folder. If you use maven to create and manage the project, the "META-INF" folder is also unser the class path.

For example, if you put the themes under "META-INF/theme", you can do the following stuff to make it works.

```
<!-- resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to allow for theme support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="META-INF.theme."/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

here the problem is not with css file actually ResourcebundleThemeSource trying to find theme-default.properties file in rot of classpath .ie. under the src folder. so put your all properties file under thier, and i am sure your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the i18N features in your application , regarding the localization if yes, then you need to add the below code

```
<"bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
  <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
</bean>
```

Otherwise remove your code `<ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />` from the below code

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="interceptors">
    <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I hope this code will work properly.....